# Get the average monthly value from 2 SP List columns and display in new column

Tags: sharepoint

I need to calculate the average value for each month. Currently I have 2 columns "DATE" (date value e.g 01/01/2010) and AccOpen (number value). So for all dates within January I need to return the average value of all numbers contained in the corresponding AccOpen rows for January dates.

Is it possible to use the **CALCULATED** option and input a **FORMULA** that will return the average for all itmes within each months period (when adding a column to the list ?

DATE    ACCOPEN AVERAGE
01/01/2010  2   2
02/01/2010  2
03/01/2010  2
04/01/2010  2
01/02/2010  2   2
02/02/2010  2
03/02/2010  2
04/02/2010  2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do this OOTB without writing event receiver code (or other custom code running in a batch mode).

To get you started

- [MSDN - How to: Create an Event Handler Feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453149.aspx)
- [Event Handlers : Everything you need to know...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx)

This will need to hook into the list item update and then consolidate your list into a separate summary list with the calculations you need.

The brute force approach would be to run the calculation afresh for every item in the group when an item is inserted/updated.

A smarter approach would be to just update the delta (the difference between the old and the new record) which is easier to do if you store components of the calculation - so in your case

Month - NumRecords - TotalValue

and work out the Average on the fly (as its easy to delta the NumRecords/TotalValue but impossible to apply it directly to the average)

One 3rd party web part which may fit your need is [PivotPoint](http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/pivotpoint) - it allows you to do things like sum/count/avg over groups like Month & Year *(disclaimer - I work for the company)*

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to query anything other than the current item when creating a formula field.
The only way to do this is to create custom code either within an event handler for the list or external code that processes items in the list and updates a "average" field when required.

Comment: Hi Nat, do you have any examples or any references you think I would find useful ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated field to give you the year and month, for example: 2011-07. Then modify your list view to group on the calculated field. When editing your view, there is also an option to display totals, I believe you can set this to average for your AccOpen column. If you're not interested in the details, you can choose to collapse all groups by default.

Comment: Just a heads up that this will only do the calculation for what you can see on the page. So if, for example you've got a paging size of 30 but 100 items in the list then the figure will be incorrect.